# Mean of a tsibble

Tags: r, mean, tsibble

I want to compute the mean of each series within a given tsibble. This is my code:

```
library(tsibble)

data <- tibble(
  Time = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), by = "1 months", length.out = 4),
  Series1 = c(3, 4, 1, 2), Series2 = c(0, 1, 2, 3)
)
ts <- as_tsibble(data, index = Time)

print(ts)
print(colMeans(ts))
```

It gives me

```
Error in colMeans(ts) : 'x' must be numeric
```

(This is the same error as with `colMeans(data)`.)

Why doesn't tsibble overload colMeans to ignore the date index?
What else can I use?

(This is with R 4.0.4, tsibble 1.1.4.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answers:

- tsibble does not overload colMeans, because it is generally not useful to compute overall means of time series.
- Instead, I can convert to tibble (in case `data` is not available any more), remove the time index, then call `colMeans`:

  ```
  library(dplyr)
  ts_data <- select(tibble(ts), -Time)
  print(colMeans(ts_data))
  ```

Comment: Since you no longer want a time series in the output, then it is correct to convert it back to a tibble. A tsibble will try to retain the time structure when manipulating the data.